# How to stop foreverjs?

Tags: node.js, forever

I've been trying to kill a node process running with forever.

I've tried `sudo forever stop 0` and `sudo forever stopall` but a new forever process always respawns?

Any ideas?

Comment: `sudo kill -9 <procid>`  Or, alternatively, [pkill -9 ...](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill)

Comment: Sounds like you have a script to auto start it

Comment: @MrOffice but if that were the case the script would have to be launched by something right? I haven't restarted the server or started anything else really for it to be able to kick off a script.

Comment: @paulsm4, I tried kill, but it's the same effect as `killall` which i didn't particularly want to use but did anyway for lack of a better option

Comment: Have you tried ``forever list`` to get the id of forever process and then ``forever stop %that_id%``?

Comment: @AlexanderM. Yup, and it will stop that process but another will immediately start

Answer (score 0):

try to kill the node precess then,
try `sudo killall node`, or as root, `ps aux | grep -i node | awk {'print $2'} | xargs kill -9`

Comment: Tried `sudo killall node` and didn't work, but I thought forever was to prevent unplanned end to processes?